# Книги по архитектуре?

Tags: архитектура, книги

Можете подсказать толковые книги по строению архитектуры?

Comment: Уточните что вы подразумеваете под архитектурой. Это дизайн зданий? Может архитектура процессоров?

Comment: Архитектура приложений.

Answer (score 1):

- Архитектура программного обеспечения на практике, Басс
- Архитектура корпоративных программных приложений, Фаулер

Comment: John Brown А вы читали Крэг Лармана? Если да то как вам? И какая из 2-3 этих книг приоритетнее?

Comment: Лармана не читал. Из тех, что посоветовал: Басс - для начала, чтобы разобраться в основах, а Фаулер - ближе к завершению, когда уже будет понимание темы.

Comment: А как вам эта книга? "UML 2 и Унифицированный процесс. Практический объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование" Вы с ней сталкивались?

Answer (score 0):

Крэг Ларман. Применение UML 2.0 и шаблонов проектирования. Введение в объектно-ориентированный анализ, проектирование и итеративную разработку

Comment: Мда... Ни в одном интернет магазине этой книги нет..)

Comment: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3105480/

Comment: Видел.. Я всмысле в наличии ни где нет...

Comment: Запланируйте поход по книжным магазинам, книжка стоящая, если действительно интересен ООАиД

Comment: Я на 100% уверен, что в моем городе её не найти..) Поэтому всегда заказываю через интернет магазины.. У меня даже Макконнелла ни где нет и Фаулера.. Дефицит на все как в Советские...

Comment: А как вам эта книга? "UML 2 и Унифицированный процесс. Практический объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование" Вы с ней сталкивались?